# Problem with starting point of SVG animation for a path/arc

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm trying to animate this SVG path/arc, from the beginning point to the end point, but I can not achieve that. Actually, the animation starts at the midpoint of the arc.

My arc's code is:

```css
#arc {
  display: block;
  stroke-dashoffset: 3925px;
  stroke-dasharray: 3925px;
}

#arc {
  -webkit-animation: dashAnim 1s 1s linear alternate forwards;
  animation: dashAnim 1s 1s linear alternate forwards;
}

@keyframes dashAnim {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 3925px;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="arc" viewBox="0 0 1922 100.2">
       <path id="arc-stroke" fill="none" stroke="#FF0000" strokeWidth="5" 
       strokeMiterlimit="10" d="M969.3,21.9c-344.4,0-669.8,82.4-956.8,229.7v6
       h1922.3C1646,106.7,1317.2,21.9,969.3,21.9z"/>
</svg>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: The stroke array always starts at the beginning of the path...would that be it?

Comment: Paulie_D, weird that my starts at midpoint, you can see it, when you run the code snippet above, I mean the animation.

Comment: It's not at all weird. Set the overflow css property on your svg to visible. You'll see the rest of the shape you're drawing, and the fact that the drawing starts in the middle of that arc that is originally visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When opened in application like Illustrator, your path had additional points off canvas. I cleaned them up and the animation seems to work as you wanted.

There were no other obvious problems with the path that I could find.

My guess is - when you animate a closed path that is effectively a circle, something has to be the beginning and the end. In this case it was the middle of the arc.

```css
#arc {
  display: block;
  stroke-dashoffset: 3925px;
  stroke-dasharray: 3925px;
}

#arc {
  -webkit-animation: dashAnim 1s 1s linear alternate forwards;
  animation: dashAnim 1s 1s linear alternate forwards;
}

@keyframes dashAnim {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 3925px;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="arc" viewBox="0 0 1922 100.2">
       <path id="arc-stroke" fill="none" stroke="#FF0000" strokeWidth="5" 
       strokeMiterlimit="10" d="M1591.4,115.8c-196.6-61.1-405.6-93.9-622.1-93.9c-218.8,0-430,33.3-628.5,95.3"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Serg, I did as you told and it works. Actually it was primary a circle in my AI file, and I only reduced the art board so that it looked as a arc. I guess the problem was the other part of that circle that was outside of the art board. So I did it look like an real arc and cut the rest of the circle.Thank you.